# Pivoting Text in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have an excel spreadhseet where I am pulling in data from an external data source.  I really would like to group and/or pivot the data to use for data validation.

What I want to do is take this:

```
NAME               |  COMPANY ID  
Abraham Lincoln    |  USG
Janet Jackson      |  JS5
John Kennedy       |  USG
Steve Jobs         |  APL
```

And make this:

```
      USG        |        JS5      |      APL
ABRAHAM LINCOLN  |  JANET JACKSON  |  STEVE JOBS
JOHN KENNEDY     |                 |
```

---

I've tried to use a pivot table, but I can't get figure out how to get the actual text to display in the "values" section for each column.

Using the "count" option for NAME, I can see where each name lands in each company, but I just can't figure out the last part of getting the names to display.

I need them to be in-column so I can use them for data validation. 
I also need the columns to be dynamically linked to the source table (hence the pivot table) so that anytime I refresh the query my pivoted data updates as well.

---

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. 
I am pulling in the external data using MS-Query. I would be open to pivoting data there as well.  I tried to use `pivot` and `group by` commands in the SQL string but could not get them to work (I don't know if MS-Query supports such SQL commands).

[image: Example of pivot table]

Answer (score 0):

THis can be done using the PowerQuery addin, or by using VBA and a workaround. Both approaches are detailed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767117/pivot-in-excel-without-aggregation-to-show-text-not-numbers/